# Axios with Auth is not a valid axios instance

Tags: react-native, axios

I'm trying to set Authorization headers on an axios post request using axios.create().  I have this in a file and when I try to import the function into my React Native component, I get the following error:

`axiosWithAuth.default().post is not a function`

below is my code for the function:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import {AsyncStorage} from 'react-native';
// import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage'

async function axiosWithAuth() {
    const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken');
    console.log('token from asyncstorage' , token);
    return axios.create({headers : {'Content-Type': null, Authorization : token}})
}

export default axiosWithAuth;
```

and I'm using the function in the following React Native Component:

```
import axiosWithAuth from '../utils/axiosWithAuth';

const Recipe = (props) => {

const likeIt = () => {
        console.log('like pressed');
        console.log('props', props.recipe.id);
        setLike(!like);
        axiosWithAuth().post(`API_URL`,{})
            .then(res => console.log('response from post like: ', res.data))
            .catch(err => console.log('error in posting like', err.response))
    }
return (
      <Text>This is the Recipe Component </Text>
   )
}
```

Comment: You can use axios interceptors to do add headers in a more manageable way. Take a look at the Interceptors section of the official doc of [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios)

Answer (score 0):

You used `async` with axiosWithAuth function. It is returning a `Promise`, not an instance of `axios`. You have to write it like this

```
(await axiosWithAuth()).post(`API_URL`,{})
    .then(res => console.log('response from post like: ', res.data))
    .catch(err => console.log('error in posting like', err.response))
```

Comment: Okay.  I did that, however, I I'm still getting a promise rejection:  
`[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: (0, _axiosWithAuth.default)().post is not a function. (In '(0, _axiosWithAuth.default)().post("https://url" + props.recipe.id, {})', '(0, _axiosWithAuth.default)().post' is undefined)]`

Comment: `const likeIt = async () => {
        console.log('like pressed');
        console.log('props.recipe.id: ', props.recipe.id);
        setLike(!like);
        console.log('axiosWithAuth(): ', await axiosWithAuth());
        await axiosWithAuth().post(`https://url/likes/${props.recipe.id}`,{})
            .then(res => console.log('response from post like: ', res.data))
            .catch(err => console.log('error in posting like', err.response))
    }`

Comment: brackets are important here. `await axiosWithAuth().post` won't work. You have to write it `(await axiosWithAuth ()).post`. If it still doesn't work, you should provide a code sample.

Comment: Hi @mark . When I declared a separate variable to be the await axiosWithAuth() then it did end up working.  Thanks!

Comment: `const axiosAuth = await axiosWithAuth();` and `(await axiosWithAuth())` are basically the same thing. You are waiting until the Promise returns an axios instance and then assigning it to a variable. I am doing the same but I am using it directly without assigning it to a variable. I tested that and it works. You can accept my answer if you want :)

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code that worked.  Create a variable and set it = await axiosWithAuth().  Then do a post request off of the variable.  Below is the axiosWithAuth function definition:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import {AsyncStorage} from 'react-native';

async function axiosWithAuth() {
    const userToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken');
    console.log('userToken', userToken);
    // return axios.create({headers : {'Content-Type': null, Authorization : userToken}})
    return axios.create({headers : {Authorization : userToken}})
}

export default axiosWithAuth;
```

and below is the code that is using the axiosWithAuth function:

```
import axiosWithAuth from '../utils/axiosWithAuth';

const likeIt = async () => {
        await setLike(!like);
        console.log('liked?', like);
        const axiosAuth = await axiosWithAuth();
        console.log('axiosAuth', axiosAuth);
        if (!like) {
            axiosAuth.post(`https://url`,{})
                .then(res => {
                    console.log('response from post like: ', res.data.message);
                })
                .catch(err => console.log('error in posting like', err.response))
        } else {
            axiosAuth.delete(`https://url`)
                .then(res => console.log('res from unlike', res))
                .catch(err => console.log('err from deleting like', err))
        }
    }
```